# MYSQL database Calculation

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to calculate an age to a specific date in MYSQL i know we can find the age using CURDATE option but how to include a specific date and a year to the calculation?
eg:- calculate the age of a person as at the 1st of August each year!

regards.

Comment: Just put the date where you'd put `curdate()` in your calculating expression.

Comment: yeah but it has to be every year,

Comment: Show us how you'd do it using the curdate option

Comment: SELECT *, YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birthdate) AS age FROM user;

Answer (score 0):

In general you store the date of birth of a person, not the age.

You can have the age of a person as an extra [redundant] column; if you do, you'll need to schedule a nightly process every midnight to update this column. If for any reason this nightly process crashes, your column will have stale (possibly wrong) values.

Comment: yeah but i need a solution to include each year for my calculation. day and the month can be specified in place were we would use CURDATE(). but year cannot be stored as it changes